# Как с помощью mangoose найти последний элемент БД?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Всем привет! В БД (mongo) имеется массив orders, как с помощью mangoose мне найти последний элемент c orderNumber=116 (причем orderNumbers начинается не с 0) и, чтобы следующий order записать с номером 117. По документации, если я правильно понял, метод Order.findOne({"OrderNumber"},...) возвращает не последний элемент БД.

```
var orders = [
  ...,
  new Order({
    orderNumber: 116,
    cart: new Cart({
      items: [
        {item: "Item1", qty: qty1, price: price1}
      ],
      totalQty: totalQty1,
      totalPrice: totalPrice1
    })
  })
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
orders.find().sort({orderNumber:-1}).limit(1);
```

-1 сортировка по номеру в обратном порядке (1 сортировка по порядку)